# Azure Logic Apps Liquid connector – transform HTML to XML

Tags: azure, transformation, azure-logic-apps

We are having HTML response, need to transform it to XML/JSON.

Anybody can help, how to achieve it through an Azure Logic app and Integration Account.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: do you have an example of what you need to parse and transform into XML/JSON?

Answer (score 0):

So, what you have is not really a technical issue with LogicApps or Liquid.

Scrubbing/Parsing/Transforming HTML is a challenge for any platform and should be considered separate from any processing or logic you intend to apply.

There are some HTML cleaning/formatting services you can subscribe to and call from the Logic App or you can write/purchase a library you can run in an Azure Function, also callable from the Logic App.